# How to give up on switch case in favor of polymorphism React?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

My React application implements two business cases. They are similar in many ways, but differs in, for example, executable methods during the process:

Case A: doHardWork()

Case B: doSimpleWork()

The results of this methods are processed equally and previous methods can be the same too.
Every time than I need to use one of these methods I am forced to use switch/case construction to define what method I will use exactly. 
For solving this situation I want to use something like polymorphism, but don't see that it is possible, because methods doHardWork and doSimpleWork refer on MOBX store variables and another methods. So I can't incapsulate the logic of specific business case to the specific class.

Please help to avoid switch/case. The project become overweighted because of it and hard to expand.

Comment: I don't know about mobx, but the react docs do not recommend using inheritance (hence polymorphism) when using components: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance

Comment: @jhujhul thank you, I saw this documentation, but my answer is not about components, sorry, that I couldn't formulate my answer better..

Comment: @Vera, how it is determined which one to be called(doHardWork or doSimpleWork). Is it at runtime(based on user action, etc.) or you know exactly which one will be called?

Comment: @AntoanElenkov I have select field, where user can choose buisiness case mode A or B. Than user presses the button and the process starts, for example user persses "Start" button and method start() executes. `  const start = () => {
  switch (mode) {
      case 'A': {doHardWork(); break}
      case 'B': {doSimpleWork(); break}
    }
  }`

Comment: @Vera, this is not related to mobx. This is standard situation, in which you don't know which type to use at compile time. Your instantiation of A or B is at runtime based on user input, so I don't think it is possible to remove this condition. BUT if you want more elegant solution(testable with DI) you can create factory, which will create the proper instance and call the method without knowing which business case exactly is executing it(polymorpihsm). Let me know if you want to show you with code example in the answers.